# Issue with use of project reactor's flatMap and switchIfEmpty operators

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have an issue with a reactive chain relying on `flatMap()` and `switchIfEmpty()`. For some reason, one of the `Mono` does not emit anything...

This is the public handler method calling the others:

```
//Throws: NoSuchElementException: Source was empty
public Mono<ServerResponse> createUser(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    Hooks.onOperatorDebug();
    Mono<User> userMono = serverRequest.bodyToMono(User.class);
    return validateUser(userMono)
        .switchIfEmpty(saveUser(userMono))
        .single();
}
```

This is the first method called by `createUser`. Note that **it is not called from a `switchIfEmpty()`** (see above) and it **does emit** an error if there is any.

```
private Mono<ServerResponse> validateUser(Mono<User> userMono) {
    return userMono
        .map(this::computeErrors)
        .filter(AbstractBindingResult::hasErrors)
        .flatMap(err ->
            status(BAD_REQUEST)
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(err.getAllErrors()))
        );
}
```

This is just a helper method:

```
private AbstractBindingResult computeErrors(User user) {
    AbstractBindingResult errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(user, User.class.getName());
    userValidator.validate(user, errors);
    return errors;
}
```

This is the `saveUser` method. It **does not emit any result!!**. It is called from a `switchIfEmpty` (see above).

```
private Mono<ServerResponse> saveUser(Mono<User> userMono) {
    return userMono
        .flatMap(userRepository::save)
        .flatMap(newUser -> status(CREATED)
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(newUser))
        );
}
```

However, if I just call the `saveUser` method directly, it will emit a result.

```
//Works fine
public Mono<ServerResponse> createUser(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
    Hooks.onOperatorDebug();
    Mono<User> userMono = serverRequest.bodyToMono(User.class);
    return saveUser(userMono) // Compare this to the above version
        .single();
}
```

Can anyone please help figure out why the `saveUser` method does not emit anything when called from a `switchIfEmpty()`?

Here is the error I get:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: Source was empty
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(MonoSingle.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.3.0.RC1.jar:3.3.0.RC1]
        Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingleMono] :
        reactor.core.publisher.Mono.single(Mono.java:3898)
        org.example.contracttestingdemo.handler.UserHandler.createUser(UserHandler.java:55)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not to do with `flatMap()` or `switchIfEmpty()` directly - it's because you're trying to consume the same `Mono` twice:

```
Mono<User> userMono = serverRequest.bodyToMono(User.class);
return validateUser(userMono)
    .switchIfEmpty(saveUser(userMono))
    .single();
```

In the above example, you're passing `userMono` first to `validateUser()`, and then to `saveUser()` (but by that point the `User` has already been emitted.)

If you want the publisher to be subscribed to multiple times, and output the same result, you'll need to cache it by calling `serverRequest.bodyToMono(User.class).cache();`.

Comment: Very interesting... It works fine indeed. I am going to read the docs about the **`cache()`** operator. Thanks again Michael!