# Debugging "NoSuchElementException: Source was empty" errors with project reactor

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am looking for tips on how to pinpoint such errors as:

```
NoSuchElementException: Source was empty
```

whilst using project reactor. This indicates that the `Mono/Flux` did not emit any result but how I am supposed to find out the reason for that?

I currently use `Hooks.onOperatorDebug();` which is very helpful, but I am looking for other ways of spotting the cause of such errors.

Any advice or recommendation on best practices welcome.

*P.S. I have opened another question here: [Issue with use of project reactor's flatMap and switchIfEmpty operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836568) related to this one.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using `log()` can go a long way here.

Take something like the following:

```
Flux.range(0, 5)
        .log("Initial")
        .filter(x -> x%2==0)
        .log("Even only")
        .filter(x -> x<3)
        .log("Less than 3 only")
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Which, taking the relevant bit out the log, will show:

```
21:08:28.809 [main] INFO Initial - | onNext(0)
21:08:28.809 [main] INFO Even only - | onNext(0)
21:08:28.809 [main] INFO Less than 3 only - | onNext(0)
0
21:08:28.809 [main] INFO Initial - | onNext(1)
21:08:28.809 [main] INFO Initial - | onNext(2)
21:08:28.810 [main] INFO Even only - | onNext(2)
21:08:28.810 [main] INFO Less than 3 only - | onNext(2)
2
21:08:28.810 [main] INFO Initial - | onNext(3)
21:08:28.810 [main] INFO Initial - | onNext(4)
21:08:28.810 [main] INFO Even only - | onNext(4)
```

This allows us to deduce *where* each element is being filtered, or if it was even emitted in the first place. From the above we can deduce:

- `0` was emitted, made it past the "Even only" filter, then past the "Less than 3 only" filter;
- `1` was emitted, but didn't get past the first filter
- `2` and `3` have the same patterns as `0` and `1` respectively
- `4` made it past the "Even only" filter, but went no further (so failed at the second filter)
- `5` and above, or any other elements, weren't ever emitted from the initial `Flux.range()` call.

With something like the above approach on your previous question, you may have noticed that `userMono` was never emitting anything the second time it was called, which may have helped narrow down the problem.